# Get twitter message thread like facebook

Tags: objective-c, twitter

I'm dealing with twitter api for obtaining direct messages. I checked all apis related to messages and found that Twitter doesn't offer a convenient way to get an inbox thread like Facebook. Instead of that, twitter offer separate apis for get direct message (sent by our friends), get sent direct message (sent my us). Do you know how to get a thread like facebook inbox thread so that I can show them in my Inbox screen? Or do you know how to handle these results to create inbox threads?

Answer (score 0):

Each direct message is an entity by itself, and cannot be associated with the previous messages. 
So when you get a reply it is a new direct message from you to the other user. You need to create a new message and get the senders ID then you will direct it to that ID as a new message.

Comment: THanks for your response but u don't understand my question (or my question not clear enough). I mean Facebook groups related Messages (same sender and repicient) while Twitter doesn't.

Comment: @lenhhoxung Oh, I'm sorry about that. I'm not sure if Twitter actually support that. I would suggest to post your question on their forum, they are usually pretty good at responding back. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, finally I solved by manually arranging messages. I had to compare repicient id and sender id. Twitter made our life harder

Comment: @lenhhoxung Great to know! Good luck with the rest of the project :)